# Wordpress down - no changes

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, file-permissions

Wordpress website went down without any changes.

Here are the error messages:

> Warning: include(/home/theme/public_html/wp-content/themes/sachba/functions.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/user/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 425
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/sachbaco/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/user/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 425
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/user/public_html/wp-settings.php:425) in /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1195

Any help please?

Comment: Its file permission issue check that

Comment: can you please share your code of functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting permission on  /home/user/public_html/wp-settings.php to 777 and try again. if it works then you must lower the permissions one by one until the error appears. *Do not leave wp-settings.php on 777 for a long time.

Comment: Working. Thanks.